# What is the capture button element id in the view finder of the camera in selendroid. I am not able to inspect it

Tags: android, testing, camera, selendroid

I want to know what is the capture button **element id** in the view finder of the camera in selendroid.
I am not able to inspect it. How to inspect the system apps. Here I am invoking the camera native app through my application to store the photo. But I am not able to inspect and get the element ID of the camera capture button. Please help

Comment: Can somebody help me on this. I am stuck. Anybody working on Selendroid...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with selendroid a bit. By here is some problem with Selendroid. You cant operate outside application which is under test.